# Menu hover effect is not working in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, internet-explorer, menu

I am working on project in which I have used hoverd menu. Which is working fine in Chrome and FF. But now working in IE7 and IE8. This menu is dynamically binded to the form. as shown below.

[image]

Whatever menu effect you are seeing is happening well inside Chrome. But not in IE as shown below.

[image]

My CSS file is as follow.

```
/* reset  list style */
.cbp-tm-menu,
.cbp-tm-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
}

/* set menu position; change here to set to relative or float, etc. */
.cbp-tm-menu {
    font-family: "Bebas Neue";
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color:#2b343b;
    margin:0;

}

/* first level menu items */
.cbp-tm-menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left:21px;

}

.cbp-tm-menu > li > a {
    line-height: 3em;
    padding-right:1em;
    font-size: 23px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;

}

.no-touch .cbp-tm-menu > li > a:hover,
.no-touch .cbp-tm-menu > li > a:active {
    color: #e82c5c;
}

/* sumbenu with transitions */
.cbp-tm-submenu {
    position: absolute;

    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0s;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0s;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0s;

}

.cbp-tm-show .cbp-tm-submenu {
    width: 10em;
    left: 30%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -8em;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    pointer-events: auto;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.3s;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.3s;
}

.cbp-tm-show-above .cbp-tm-submenu {
    bottom: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.cbp-tm-show-below .cbp-tm-submenu {
    top: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.cbp-tm-menu > li:hover
{
    background-color: Gray;

}


/* extreme cases: not enough space on the sides */
.cbp-tm-nospace-right .cbp-tm-submenu {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
}

.cbp-tm-nospace-left .cbp-tm-submenu {
    left: 0;
}

/* last menu item has to fit on the screen */
.cbp-tm-menu > li:last-child .cbp-tm-submenu {
    /*right: 0;*/
}

/*  
arrow: depending on where the menu will be shown, we set 
the right position for the arrow
*/

.cbp-tm-submenu span {
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;

}
.cbp-tm-show-above .cbp-tm-submenu span{
    border-top-color: #fff;
}

.cbp-tm-show-below .cbp-tm-submenu span{
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
.cbp-tm-show-above .cbp-tm-submenu span {
    top: 100%;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

.cbp-tm-show-below .cbp-tm-submenu span {
    bottom: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}
.cbp-tm-submenu span {
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 16px;
    margin-left: -26px;
    left: 64px;
}

.cbp-tm-submenu > li {
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
}
.cbp-tm-submenu > li > a {
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0.6em; /* top/bottom paddings in 'em' cause a tiny "jump" in Chrome on Win */
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
    color: #e82c5c;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

.no-touch .cbp-tm-submenu > li > a:hover,
.no-touch .cbp-tm-submenu > li > a:active {
    color: #fff;
    background: #e82c5c;
}
/* the icons (main level menu icon and sublevel icons) */
.cbp-tm-submenu li a:before,
.cbp-tm-menu > li > a:before {
    speak: none;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-variant: normal;
text-transform: none;
line-height: 1;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-right: 0.6em;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 }

 .cbp-tm-submenu li a:before {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -0.5em;

}
.cbp-tm-menu > li > a:not(:only-child):before {
    opacity: 0.3;
 }


/* Media Queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 55.6875em) {
.cbp-tm-menu {
    font-size: 80%;
}
}

 @media screen and (max-height: 25.25em), screen and (max-width: 44.3125em) {

.cbp-tm-menu {
    font-size: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    top: auto;
}

.cbp-tm-menu > li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
}

.cbp-tm-menu > li:first-child {
    border-top: 4px solid #000;
}

li.cbp-tm-show > a,
.no-touch .cbp-tm-menu > li > a:hover,
.no-touch .cbp-tm-menu > li > a:active {
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
}

.cbp-tm-submenu {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;

}

.cbp-tm-submenu > li {
    padding: 0;
}

.cbp-tm-submenu > li > a {
    padding: 0.6em 2.3em 0.6em 0.6em;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

.cbp-tm-submenu:after {
    display: none;
}

.cbp-tm-menu .cbp-tm-show .cbp-tm-submenu {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

}
```

Here is my http://jsbin.com/eyUjUHET/4/.

Comment: if you didn't fix the problem yet, post the site link or filddle us to help you. it will helpful to debug.

Comment: @Kirk- i have binded it dynamically....

Comment: @Kirk- look to jsfiddle... i have updated it

Comment: that is not showing dropdowns on chrome too?

Comment: @nop its showing it in chrome too.... i have uploded wrong js....

Comment: ok, update the correct one, ill have a look

Answer (score 0):

You are missing CSS Rendering engine for IE. Different browsers have different rendering engine.

1. Chrome -webkit
2. Firefox -moz
3. Opera -According to my knowledge, opera has already switched to open source -webkit rendering engine.
4. Internet Explorer. I think that internet explorer uses Trident Rendering Engine.

**-webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.3s;**

**-moz-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.3s;**

You should use Trident Engine in your CSS just like you have used webkit engine for chrome.

Comment: I think that Internet Explorer 9, and earlier versions, does not support the transition property.

Comment: its IE8 .. and i got that by this link... http://caniuse.com/css-transitions is there anyother way to use it?

Answer (score 0):

For <= IE9, you'll have to animate with JavaScript.

jQuery offers [`$().animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). To keep your CSS transitions for the best performance in modern browsers, you can use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to only include script that calls `animate()` if the browser is IE9 or below.

Comment: I just noticed that I was answering "this needs to animate in IE7 & IE8", not your actual question of "this needs to show". I'm sorry about that. Could you post the site link or create a jsfiddle so we can help you debug it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method I know for such a situation is the following:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/selectivizr.min.js"></script>       
<![endif]-->
```

You can get the scripts from:

- [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)
- [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/)

They always come in handy, even IE6 ends up supporting HTML5 and CSS3 :D

Comment: i have done that... i have made one css called ie.css... if its IE then it will work on that css...